# Calling getElementsByTagNameNS from GWT code

Tags: javascript, xml, gwt

I have an XML document in the form of com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document object. Since there is no 'getElementsByTagNameNS' API provided on the Document class, is it possible to use some native Javascript functions to achieve the same?

The API should take two parameters 
1 - Namespace prefix.
2 - XML tag name.

I need this because, the recent Chrome update (v60) does not return the NodeList for Document.getElementsByTagName("book") if the XML tag has a namespace prefix.

Answer (score 0):

c.g.g.xml never supported namespaces, and is thus not meant to be used with documents using XML namespaces. It also wraps the native objects and doesn't give any access to them.

Nowadays, I suppose there's almost no difference in browser support of the APIs (that wasn't the case with IE6 for example), so you'd better rewrite your code to use JsInterop instead of c.g.g.xml (have a look at Elemental 2, which should already have the "mappings")

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a quick and dirty alternative to the `getElementsByTagName` function. It takes the fully qualified tag name and returns all the descendant element nodes that have the exact tag name.

```
/**
 * Builds a list of the descendant elements with the supplied tag name from the {@code parent} node. The result
 * nodes are ordered by a depth-first traversal of the element graph.
 * 
 * @param tag   {@link String} = The tag we are looking for. Fully qualified with the namespace if present (e.g. {@code hh:label})
 * @param parent    {@link Node} = Root node of the search
 * @return {@link List<Node>} = The node list
 */
public static List<Node> getElementsByTagName(String tag, Node parent) {
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (parent == null) {
        return result;
    }

    NodeList children = parent.getChildNodes();
    for (int childIdx = 0; childIdx < children.getLength(); childIdx++) {
        Node child = children.item(childIdx);
        if (child.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            continue;
        }
        if (((Element) child).getTagName() == tag) {
            result.add(child);
        }
        getElementsByTagName(tag, child, result);
    }
    return result;
}

private static void getElementsByTagName(String tag, Node parent, List<Node> partialResult) {
    if (parent == null) {
        return;
    }

    NodeList children = parent.getChildNodes();
    for (int childIdx = 0; childIdx < children.getLength(); childIdx++) {
        Node child = children.item(childIdx);
        if (child.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            continue;
        }
        if (((Element) child).getTagName() == tag) {
            partialResult.add(child);
        }
        getElementsByTagName(tag, child, partialResult);
    }
}
```